# instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-ZWG-5q-24I" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, uipickerview

I am trying to go from a UIPickerView selection to UITableViewController.  When a user selects a year it is supposed to go to UITableView to display a list of driver standings for a given year.  The problem I am having is that the UINavigationController is not the rootViewController. As I am producing the UITableViewController programmatically.  If it was then I know I would implement this code in the AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
     window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: StandingTableViewController())
    return true
}
```

This is not correct as this would go straight to a UITableViewController.  Below is the code for the UIPickerView.

```
extension seasonViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return seasons.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return seasons[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    selectedSeason = seasons[row]
    seasonTextField.text = selectedSeason
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "getStanding" {
        let standingVC = segue.destination as! StandingTableViewController

        standingVC.standing = seasonTextField.text!

    }
}
```

This is the code for the TableViewController.

```
class StandingTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var standing = ""
let SEASON_URL = "https://ergast.com/api/f1"

var champions: [DriverStanding] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.title = standing

    fetchJSON(standing: standing)

}
```

I am trying to avoid doing this in a storyboard.  Or will I have to create UITableView in the storyboard in this instance? Just to let you know that UIPickerView is part of a TabView App. Sorry for this late addition. Not sure if this would make a difference to the answer. [image: Storyboard layout]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a `UITableViewController` loaded from a storyboard, the `view` outlet needs to be initialized to a `UITableView`.

Comment: So I need to add a UITableView into the storyboard then?

Answer (score 0):

From your image it looks like you used plain `UIViewController` in storyboard and set him `StandingTableViewController` class, which is subclass of `UITableViewController`.

Because of it you getting normal `UIView` instead of `UITableView` as `view`.

To fix it, remove your controller in storyboard and add new `UITableViewContoller` instead and set his class to `StandingTableViewController`

Comment: Unfortunately, the above answer does not solve my question.

Comment: @AltBrian With your addition to question I changed my answer take a look

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. Thanks very much for your reply.   As I added a `navigationController?.title = standing` programmatically will this show in the UITableViewController.